# Hover Header to Display Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I want to hover a header that I created in html to display hidden text, but I can't figure out how to do it in jQuery.

I have the following html right where I have the Print Only header I want to display the div that contains the text Hey.

```
<fieldset class="formats">
    <legend>Format Interested</legend>
    <div class="col1">
        <h2 class="test">Print Only</h2>
        <div class="info"><p>Hey</p></div>
        <input type="checkbox" name='PrintOnly[]' value='8x12' />8" x 12" - $50.00 USD<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name='PrintOnly[]' value='12x18' />12" x 18" - $90.00 USD<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name='PrintOnly[]' value='16x24' />16" x 24" - $125.00 USD<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name='PrintOnly[]' value='20x30' />20" x 30"- $160.00 USD
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <h2>Framed Prints</h2>
        <input type="checkbox" name='FramedPrints[]' value='8x12' />8" x 12"- $175.00 USD*<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name='FramedPrints[]' value='12x18' />12" x 18"- $230.00 USD*<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name='FramedPrints[]' value='16x24' />16" x 24"- $375.00 USD*<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name='FramedPrints[]' value='20x30' />20" x 30"- $425.00 USD*
        <p><em>* Frame prices can vary based on framing materials used.</em></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
        <h2>Floating Gallery Wrap</h2>
        <input type="checkbox" name='FloatingGalleryWrap[]' value='8x12' />8" x 12"- $115.00 USD<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name='FloatingGalleryWrap[]' value='16x24' />16" x 24"- $275.00 USD<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name='FloatingGalleryWrap[]' value='20x30' />20" x 30"- $360.00 USD
    </div>
    <div class="col4">
        <h2>Fine Art Canvas Print</h2>
        <input type="checkbox" name='FineArtCanvasPrint[]' value='12x28' />12" x 28" - $200.00 USD<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name='FineArtCanvasPrint[]' value='16x24' />16" x 24" - $275.00 USD<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name='FineArtCanvasPrint[]' value='20x30' />20" x 30" - $360.00 USD
    </div>
</fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="photoid" value="<?php echo $photo['Photo']['id'];?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="galleryname" value="<?php echo $photo['Gallery']['name'];?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="photofilename" value="<?php echo $photo['Photo']['filename'];?>"/>
<input class="buttonsend" id="ajaxformsend" type="button" value="Send Request" onclick="sendform();return false;"/><div class="cleaner"></div>

</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have to give credit to antimatterfish for getting it started, but I think I cleaned it up to be what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/8a8T7/

Hover over "Print Only" to make the "Hey" *visible*.

Comment: Yeah I just did what you did before you posted but this is the right answer. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.test').hover(
function(){ $('.info').show();}, 
    function(){ $('.info').hide();
});
```

Comment: Hmm I tried this but it didn't do anything unfortunately though it seems to be in the right direction from what I researched.

Comment: Hmm, it works in the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/4FG7h/ Try playing around with the divs? Use id instead of class, or put the header inside a div and set the jquery on that. Not really sure what the issue is.

Comment: Hmm yeah not sure either will poke around a bit to see if I get your answer working on my project. Thanks I appreciate you taking the time in helping me.

Comment: +1 works fine.  Should have a `.` instead of a `#` in the CSS in order to see the effect the first time, however.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was testing with ids and classes, and I guess I forgot to change the css. Thanks for voting up, though! =P

Comment: Thats the magic of programming so many different ways to answer a problem :)